# Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -9) when printing a report with a large number of records

Tags: odoo, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-14

**Odoo Community Edition version 14** / **Wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.6 (with patched qt)**

When printing a report with a large number of records (for example, printing standard Sale Order report with more than 300 records), the system displays this error after waiting for a while.

> Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -9). Message: b"

This error happens in every report when the number of records is high enough.

I have searched in Google and the [official Github issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues). There are no solutions to this problem.

I have already set `client_max_body_size` to 25M in nginx, but the problem still persists.

I would like to solve this error and successfully print reports with large number of records.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The easiest and probably most hateful solution is to print less records at once. :(

Comment: @CZoellner Have you ever faced this issue in your environments?

Comment: Yes and i've told the customer to print less then 300 records ;-) What is the special case you need to print 300 records? Oh and have you tried to add some memory to the odoo workers to lift up that 300 count?

Comment: @CZoellner No special cases, I think. I need to recheck that. About the workers, I have raised `limit_memory_hard` to the maximum of the machine's RAM and increased `limit_memory_soft` accordingly (a little bit lower then the hard one). The problem still persists. Not sure if it increases the number of maximum records I can print but still the really large number of records will cause problems.

Comment: I have done some more research. I think the issue comes from the Wkhtmltopdf library itself. That it cannot handle lots of data input at once. Moreover, the library is apparently not maintained anymore.

Comment: I may have to resort to your suggestion if there is no workaround/answer that is better than this. I still welcome any suggestions about this problem. Though, I will go with this for now.

Comment: In my early life working with OpenERP 5 i came across a case, because i was working in a warehouse using odoo. Picking 300+ customer orders was a normal case back then. So we printed them all at once. But nowadays i would just print them in batches of less then 100 at once and it would work that way, too. That's why asked for a special case.